# How CRYPTO_num_locks() will return required number of locks?

Tags: c++, openssl

https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypto_num_locks says that CRYPTO_num_locks() returns required number of locks. Previously I used CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS which was a macro with value 41 to construct a mutex array till openssl 1.0.2s. Now (OPENSSL 1.1.1d) they have introduced

`#  define CRYPTO_num_locks()            (1)`.

Hence from my understanding, the macro will have value 1, hence i surely can't use this macro for declaring a runtime array.

I can go with changing the value of macro inside crypto.h, but just wanted to know the reason why did OPENSSL changed the value they were returning for the number of locks. I went through their gitlink https://github.com/openssl/openssl and changes https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x13.

These things made me a bit clear about the use of function instead of macro, but can't understand two questions:

1. Why the value of CRYPTO_num_locks() set to only (1). And will it be safe for me to change it to say 41, or something else
2. If this was supposed to be macro only, what's the point in removing earlier macro(CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS).

Comment: "OpenSSL now uses a new threading API." is probably the reason (from the changelog). They also removed the old locking API. I'm not sure why you'd want to use that specific value if OpenSSL doesn't need it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It is useful to look at [the `1.1.1d` definition of `CRYPTO_num_locks` in `include/openssl/crypto.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1d/include/openssl/crypto.h#L212) and its vicinity:

```
 * On the other hand, the locking callbacks are no longer used.  Consequently,
 * the callback management functions can be safely replaced with no-op macros.
 */
#  define CRYPTO_num_locks()            (1)
#  define CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(func)
#  define CRYPTO_get_locking_callback()         (NULL)
#  define CRYPTO_set_add_lock_callback(func)
#  define CRYPTO_get_add_lock_callback()        (NULL)
```

So whatever your code does with that macro and the ones related to it, it is no longer relevant.

Looking even further up in that file, it turns out that this is all conditionally defined under the value of a macro called `OPENSSL_API_COMPAT`:

```
# if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT < 0x10100000L
```

This macro is intended to indicate whether application code is allowed to use older OpenSSL constructs. In stead of changing any OpenSSL header files, it would be better to actually set this macro to `0x1010000L` (or even higher) when compiling the application and then work through any constructs that are no longer available. That would ensure that the code no longer uses any deprecated `1.0.2` stuff.

---

For a very brief confirmation of what happened to the OpenSSL thread-safety model between `1.0.2` and `1.1.0`, see the answer to [the OpenSSL FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html) question *Is OpenSSL thread-safe?*:

> Yes but with some limitations; for example, an SSL connection cannot
>   be used concurrently by multiple threads. This is true for most
>   OpenSSL objects.
>
> For version 1.1.0 and later, there is nothing further
>   you need do.
>
> For earlier versions than 1.1.0, it is necessary for your
>   application to set up the thread callback functions. To do this, your
>   application must call CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(3) and one of the
>   CRYPTO_THREADID_set... API's. See the OpenSSL threads manpage for
>   details and "note on multi-threading" in the INSTALL file in the
>   source distribution.

Comment: "For version 1.1.0 and later, there is nothing further you need do." So does OpenSSL contains locks internally?